# Find out the most frequency combination and add labels

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, frequency, pandas-groupby

I have a table with my customer data like this:

```
Customer    Price
AAA            100
AAA            100
AAA            200
BBB            100
BBB            220
BBB            200
BBB            200
```

What I want to do is to find out the customer with the condition `number of price >= 200 is more than number of price < 200` and add labels for them.
for example:

```
Customer    LABELS
AAA            FALSE
BBB            TRUE
```

any ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.Price.ge(200).groupby(df.Customer).mean().gt(.5)

Customer
AAA    False
BBB     True
Name: Price, dtype: bool
```

Or if you insist on your format

```
df.Price.ge(200).groupby(df.Customer).mean().gt(.5).reset_index(name='Labels')

  Customer  Labels
0      AAA   False
1      BBB    True
```

Comment: really nice solution.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your idea. really good method for this case. just one question about function of gt(). could you tell me the reason of using 5 for gt()?

Comment: @YamPakChing it's another way of writing '> .5' and will only happen when there are more Trues as Falses

Comment: @piRSquared Amazing stuff. I'm following you around =)
@YamPakChing I think the the difference between `ge` and `gt` is the former filters `=>` and  `gt` filters only `>`  ( I just looked it up).

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you so much for your idea.

Comment: @moondra Thank you for your help, this idea is great but a little difficult to understand for Beginner

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward answer:

```
df.groupby('Customer').apply(
    lambda g: (g['Price'] >= 200).sum() > (g['Price'] < 200).sum()
)
```

Summing a boolean vector will return the number of `True` values.

Comment: Thanks , but this solution does not work in this case. I think we have to compare the frequency of price than sum of price.

Comment: Is the result not what you expected? I'm not summing the price, but a boolean vector that counts the number of times the price is above or below 200 (i.e. the frequency).

Comment: sorry, i have tried your idea again.it does work and very easy to understand. thank you very much.